# IntelliJ. Jar creation. Use files from current path of jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a IntelliJ project that can run methods from different classes inside the project folder.

My goal is to create a jar file of my project, so that jar file can interact with different classes that are located in the same folder as jar.

When I create a jar file by default it can't find files in the same folder.
I can't add files I need direct to jar.

How can I do it with IntelliJ?

Update.
My program is created to run specific methods in a given class-file(String name is given by user via UI) and then show return value to the user via UI.

How it work now:

I have a folderA with a source files of a program and class-file `testfile.java` to test the program.
I can run a program via IntelliJ, enter `testfile` via UI and the program will run some methods of testfile-class doing everything it should.

How I want it to work:

Program is packed into jar `program.jar`. User moves `program.jar` to `folderB` that contains `abc.java`.
User runs `program.jar`, enters `abc` and program stuff with `abc.java`

Comment: Show what you tried so far, show what the file structure you desire is going to look like (jar A here, jar B here, and inside the jar these contents - something like that). your question as is, is too vague.

Comment: Usually all the classes of a given project are *inside* the jar and don't tend to lie randomly in directories. Can you explain why you want to deviate from that norm? It's not impossible, but it's highly unlikely and there's a pretty good chance that there are better solutions to what you're trying to do. This could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Also by "files" do you only mean classes or are you talking about other resources (such as images, property files, ...)?

Comment: Regarding the update: `abc.java` is not a class file. That's a Java source file. `abc.class` would be a class file. Loading a class file is relatively easy (create a new `URLClassLoader` and use that to load the class), but compiling a `.java` file first adds an extra step. Also note that if the `.class` file belongs to a package, then it might become more complicated, as the classloader will expect the folder hierarchy to match the package structure.

Comment: While there are some ways to determine the location of the .jar file from which a program is running, none of them are completely reliable.  If an application wants to use dynamically available external classes,  the [Service Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) architecture is usually the best way to do it.